# assign value to datagridview cell at run time in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datagrid

I have datagrid view in which I have 3 columns.  The are name, price, and quantity.  I have populated the first 2 columns from a dataset and now I want to assign a value to quantity the column based on the data in the existing columns.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expression based columns.

Here is a good article: [Express Yourself with Expression-based Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx)

You can also take a look at [Datatable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method.